# Json response giving me different output

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am getting the same value for the 1st, 2nd and 3rd rows in my json response. The supposed result for the 2nd row displays in the second column and the 3rd result supposed in the 1st column displays in the 3rd.

```
 $sql = "select
          e_name,
          a_shortcut,
          case
            when t_rank = 1 then '1st'
            when t_rank = 2 then '2nd'
            when t_rank = 3 then '3rd'
          end as t_rank
        from
          team inner join event on team.EID = event.eid Where e_type = 'nonsport' group by event.eid";                         

         $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name); 

        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


         $response = array();

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        array_push($response, array("e_name"=>$row[0],"1st"=>$row[1], 
        "2nd"=>$row[2], "3rd"=>$row[2]));

        } 
        echo json_encode (array("nresults"=>$response));
```

Here is what im getting in my server response if my 2nd and 3rd rows are [2] and [2].

```
 {"nresults":[{"e_name":"Amateur Photography Contest","1st":"AAA","2nd":"3rd","3rd":"3rd"}]}
```

If i changed

```
1st"=>$row[1], 
        "2nd"=>$row[2], "3rd"=>$row[2] into 1st"=>$row[1], 
        "2nd"=>$row[1], "3rd"=>$row[1]
```

It becomes like this

```
{"nresults":[{"e_name":"Amateur Photography Contest","1st":"AAA","2nd":"AAA","3rd":"AAA"}]}
```

My expected output is:

```
{"nresults":[{"e_name":"Amateur Photography Contest","1st":"AAA","2nd":"BBB","3rd":"CCC"}]}
```

where "AAA" is rank 1, "BBB" is 2 and "CCC" is 3.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: `while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
        $response[] = $row;

        }` 

now check `echo "<pre/>";print_r($response);`

Comment: gives me this   [e_name] => Amateur Photography Contest
            [a_shortcut] => AAA
            [t_rank] => 3rd

Comment: i dont follow sir. What?

Comment: you need to check that printed data have all the values  what you want as expected output or not? if yes then re-ordered them inside while loop based on your desired output. also remove if there is some unnnecessary information which is not needed in the final output.Thanks

Comment: still nothing sir, can you show me how you code it sir?